# Can いそぐ be used transitively, as in べんきょうをいそぎます?

Tags: verbs, transitivity

Is

> べんきょう**を**いそぎます。

a proper sentence construction? Are there others way to use いそぎます in a sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, 急ぐ【いそぐ】 is a transitive verb and safely take を like this. You can also say 建物【たてもの】の完成【かんせい】を急ぐ, 書類【しょるい】の作成【さくせい】を急ぐ and so on.

急ぐ is also an intransitive verb, and you can express the same thing as 急いで勉強【べんきょう】します which is closer to "I study in a hurry". I think this form is much preferred in speech.